# How to Retrieve File Path from SQL Server Database and Display Image in Image Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an Images folder in my ASP.NET C# project.

I am storing the File Path of this folder in an Images table in a SQL Server Database.

I want to display an image in an image control, this image should change based on what I have selected in a Drop Down control.

I have been able to populate the DropDown with the image names, but I don't know how to select the image as they are contained within the folder mentioned above.

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: Why don't you just set the ImageUrl = Path that you retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to find your root directory through

```
  string root = Server.MapPath("~");
```

Append it with your Folder like this

```
 string path = root + "assets\\images\\products\\";
```

Then concatenate it with your filename.

```
string FileName = path+dd.SelectedItem;
```

**And to Change ImageControl**

Use dropdownselectedindexchanged event and set

```
IMGCTRL.ImageURL=FileName;
```